# Gson custom serialization not working for java.lang.Object

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am writing a custom Gson serializer

```
public class DogSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> {
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, 
JsonSerializationContext context) {

  JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
  obj.addProperty("name", "sasha");
  return obj;
}
```

I am also registering the serialzer like

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new DogSerializer());
```

Now if I do `System.out.println(gsonBuilder.create().toJson([My-Test-Class]))` the serializer is never called. I want the serializer to be called for all fields when I pass `My-test-Class`. `Object.class` doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do?

Redesign your approach if possible and bind other types. You cannot override serialization strategies for `java.lang.Object` and `com.google.gson.JsonElement` ([as of](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/3e74bb47d1a72f72873109e8f0407a34d25fe7e6/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java#L198) 2.8.1 and prior by design):

```java
// built-in type adapters that cannot be overridden
factories.add(TypeAdapters.JSON_ELEMENT_FACTORY);
factories.add(ObjectTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
```